# Displaying an image after clicking 100 times on a button

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I'm new here and I still have some difficulties in coding.
I'm trying to create an html page for some friends and I managed to create a click counter, an image which appear and disapear after some time etc

However the only thing that I can't manage to do is how I can make an image appear after clicking on the button for 100 or 1000 times. I can make the image appear after clicking on the button one time, but I don't know how to make it appear only after some clicking.

If someone can help me I'll be very glad!

```js
$button = document.querySelector('button')
$span = document.querySelector('span')

function increment() {
  $span.innerHTML++;
}

$button.addEventListener('click', increment);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    showImage();
    setInterval(hideImage, 8000);
  }, 5000);
});

function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById("imgHideShow").style.display = "none";
}

function showImage() {
  document.getElementById("imgHideShow").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<img class="prayme" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg/1024px-Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg.png">

<p>You prayed <span id='count'>0</span> times</p>

<div id="image">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/998926585691451392/WlkEVV7x_400x400.jpg">
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <button><img class="imgbutton" src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/980-9803933_emoji-emoji-pray-thankyou-thanks-praying-hands-emoji.png">
  Afficher l'image
  </button>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpmw.gif" class="browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far to meet the requirement you describe? None of the code you included seems to make an attempt to check the number of “clicks” and take action against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an if statement, checking if the innerHTML is more or equal to 100, and then call `showImage()`.

I removed code that wasn't relevant.

I added declarations to the variables by adding `let` in front the name.

I removed the button, and put an event listener directly on the image instead.

I think the rest of the code is self-explanatory.

```js
let spanElement = document.querySelector('span');
let imgButton = document.getElementById('imgbutton');

function increment() {
  spanElement.innerHTML++;
  
  if (spanElement.innerHTML >= 5) {
    showImage();
  }
}

imgButton.addEventListener('click', increment);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setInterval(hideImage, 8000);
});

function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById("imgHideShow").style.display = "none";
}

function showImage() {
  document.getElementById("imgHideShow").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 3rem;
}

#imgHideShow.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="prayme" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg/1024px-Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg.png">

<p>You prayed <span id='count'>0</span> times</p>

<div class="text-center">
  <img id="imgbutton" src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/980-9803933_emoji-emoji-pray-thankyou-thanks-praying-hands-emoji.png">
  Afficher l'image
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpmw.gif" class="hidden browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>
```

To make the code even more readable, I would also add the following it it like this:

1. Add a constant for how many times the user need to click.
2. Declare variables for all the elements that are affected.
3. Use a class (`.hidden`) to hide the image, and add/remove that class, instead of adding a style. You should only add a style if you can't toggle classes.

```js
const TARGET_TO_SHOW_IMAGE = 5;

let spanElement = document.querySelector('span');
let imgButton = document.getElementById('imgbutton');
let imgHideShow = document.getElementById("imgHideShow");
let numberOfTimesClicked = 0;

function increment() {
  numberOfTimesClicked++;
  
  if (numberOfTimesClicked >= TARGET_TO_SHOW_IMAGE) {
    showImage();
    numberOfTimesClicked = 0; // resets
  }

  spanElement.innerHTML = numberOfTimesClicked;
}

imgButton.addEventListener('click', increment);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setInterval(hideImage, 8000);
});

function hideImage() {
  imgHideShow.classList.add('hidden');
}

function showImage() {
  imgHideShow.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 3rem;
}

#imgHideShow.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="prayme" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg/1024px-Tram_icon_black_and_transparent_background.svg.png">

<p>You prayed <span id='count'>0</span> times</p>

<div class="text-center">
  <img id="imgbutton" src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/980-9803933_emoji-emoji-pray-thankyou-thanks-praying-hands-emoji.png">
  Afficher l'image
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpmw.gif" class="hidden browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have some difficulties to understand where to put the image link (the one who have to appear)!
Sorry to bother you again ><

Comment: @MarineCavaillès I don't fully understand what you mean. Which image, and what do you mean with appear? Just just an `img` with a src, and hide it with the `.hidden` class I talked about.

Comment: Ho yes! Sorry I was stupid (and english in not my first language so I didn't fully understand anything at first sorry ><)